# How do I install GTK headers/dev package on Mac OS?

Tags: matplotlib, gtk, osx-mavericks, pygtk

-Mac OSX 10.9 Mavericks -Python 2.7 -matplotlib 1.3

Hi,

I tried running matplotlib with the TKAgg backend, but ran into some issues, so I decided to try GTKAgg instead. I can do "import gtk", so I know GTK is properly installed on my machine. However, when I try "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt", I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named _backend_gdk
```

I went into my matplotlib/backends directory and couldn't find that module. It seems that I need to install the gtk dev package/headers for it to work properly. I've googled around and can't seem to find a good answer to how to go about doing this on Mac OS. Here are my questions:

1) I'm a bit unclear on the interplay between the gtk headers, gtk and matplotlib. Could someone briefly explain what exactly the headers do?

2) What is the best way to download this gtk dev package for Mac OS?

3) Will I need to uninstall and reinstall matplotlib so that it recognizes the headers?

Thank you

Mika

Comment: Look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14346090/importerror-no-module-named-backend-gdk