# ImportError: No module named _backend_gdk on Jupyter notebook with Conda

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

Hello guys getting the following error on my jupyter notebook -

Running a codeblock with `%matplotlib gtk` results in the exception

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gdk.py in <module>()
 31 from matplotlib.mathtext import MathTextParser
 32 from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D
 ---> 33 from matplotlib.backends._backend_gdk import pixbuf_get_pixels_array
 34 
 35 backend_version = "%d.%d.%d" % gtk.pygtk_version
 ImportError: No module named _backend_gdk
```

However Installing the `pygtk` package with homebrew did succeeded. Any ideas? I'm using the anaconda distribution of python

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this thread:

[ImportError: No module named _backend_gdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14346090/importerror-no-module-named-backend-gdk)

There, installing  python-gtk2-dev is recommended.

```
sudo apt-get install python-gtk2-dev
```